# Converting Java objects?

Tags: java, xml, object, jaxb, pojo

How do you convert objects of one class to objects of another class? For example, let's say Object A has the attributes "height" and "weight." How do I check to see if Object B has these same attributes? And if Object B does have similar attributes as Object A, how do I import those values to Object A and/or create a new object with those attributes and values?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Question is too broad

Comment: This is impossible in Java as it is a strict type language. The way around is to define Name-Value pair class and then store different pairs in a collection. You can transfer elements between different collections easily in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Commons-BeanUtils BeanUtilsBean, the method copyProperties

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html

Code :

BeanUtilsBean bub= BeanUtilsBean.getinstance();

bub.copyProperties(yourObject1Dest,yourObjectOrig);

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer for all cirumstances. Some of the more common cases are:

- Two classes with the same purpose, but from different libraries. Each library works only with its own type. You need to write th glue code that build an instance of A for each B and handle conversion yourself (with explicitly written code).
- Two classes with the same purpose, but you have control over *one* of the classes. Eliminate that class and only use the other.
- Two classes but *not* the same purpose, only a common aspect. If you have control over both of them. Use either *inheritance* (if one is a special case of the other), *delegation* (the two classes are unrelated, but have a common aspect can be factored out) or define an *interface* with the common aspect and have both classes implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question :

```
public class A{
int height, weight;

  public A(int height, int weight){
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
  }

  public A(A originalObject){
    height = originalObject.height;
    weight = originalObject.weight;
  }
} 

public class B extends A{
  public B(int height, int weight){
    super(height, weight);
  }

  public B(B originalObject){
    super (originalObject);
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    B bObject = new B(10,20);
    A aObject = new A(bObject);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest looking to inheritance.

One way to check if an object has certain attributes is to just start typing out what you want in the IDE, for example:

Object.height

right after typing the "." the elements of that class with show up.